# Autofac with F#

Tags: c#, f#, autofac, c#-to-f#

How would I convert the existing C# code

```cs
_containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
_containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(CommandObserver<>)).As(typeof(ICommandObserver<>));
_containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(PropertyProvider<>)).As(typeof(IPropertyProvider<>));
```

into F#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```ml
open Autofac
let _containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder()

_containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typedefof<CommandObserver<_>>)
    .As(typedefof<ICommandObserver<_>>);

_containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typedefof<PropertyProvider<_>>)
    .As(typedefof<IPropertyProvider<_>>);
```

Comment: Thanks very much ! Spot on. The only thing I needed to add was |> ignore at the end of each line, so it became :

containerBuilder.RegisterGeneric(typedefof<PropertySubject<_>>).As(typedefof<IPropertySubject<_>>) |> ignore